# Util class with static method, but need to inject value from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, encryption, spring-security, static-methods

I create application with Spring Boot and need Encryption feature.

I choose to use Spring Security to do encryption, but i facing dilemma which way should i use?

1. create encryption as final util class with static method. i prefer this way but their is a problem, i need to inject salt property from application.properties

   ```
   public final class EncryptionUtil {

       @Value("${encryption.salt}") // can't inject value from application.properties, because static property
       private static String salt;

       @Value("${encryption.password}") // can't inject value from application.properties, because static property
       private static String password;

       public static byte[] encrypt(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
           BytesEncryptor encryptor = Encryptors.standard(password, salt);
           return encryptor.encrypt(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
       }

       public static String decrypt(byte[] bytes) {
           BytesEncryptor encryptor = Encryptors.standard(password, salt);
           return new String(encryptor.decrypt(bytes));
       }
   }
   ```
2. create as service/component using @Service/@Component annotation then inject salt property using @Value from application.properties, then call using @Autowired

   ```
   @Service
   public class EncryptionService {

       @Value("${encryption.salt}")
       private String salt;

       @Value("${encryption.password}")
       private String password;

       public byte[] encrypt(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
           BytesEncryptor encryptor = Encryptors.standard(password, salt);
           return encryptor.encrypt(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
       }

       public String decrypt(byte[] bytes) {
           BytesEncryptor encryptor = Encryptors.standard(password, salt);
           return new String(encryptor.decrypt(bytes));
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Neither... Configure a `BytesEncryptor` in your configuration and inject it where needed.

Comment: Solution 1 does not work, and solution 2 works. So, the choice doesn't seem very difficult... but @M.Deinum's solution is even better.

Comment: Solution 2 works very well to your needs

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, your solution match for me